# Receiving/Reading Emails From SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I'm trying to set up `AWS SES` and i'm having problems with reading/receiving emails. Ultimately, I want to be able to use Outlook or some other mobile client app in order to view the emails sent/received to verified addresses with SES.

I have successfully verified my domain and email addresses already. Additionally, I have set up a read receipt that forwards any received emails from SES to an S3 bucket, but I am not sure how to pull down these emails using IMAP/POP3.

Do I need to create my own Email server still in conjunction with a `lambda` function to forward the received email to that server so that I can pull down those emails using a client app. Is there no way connect directly to SES using IMAP/POP3? Finally, do I need to set up the entire email stack or is there a simplified (preferably NodeJS) mail server that can be just solely pushing the emails to the client.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment IMAP/POP3 is not supported with SES. I had the similar requirement and after evaluating several approaches, I used a Lambda to forward the emails to my web mail.

You can use the following Lambda code to forward emails forwarded to a SNS topic.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var forwardFrom = process.env.from_address;
var forwardTo = process.env.to_address;
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var msgInfo = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].Sns.Message);

    // don't process spam messages
    if (msgInfo.receipt.spamVerdict.status === 'FAIL' || msgInfo.receipt.virusVerdict.status === 'FAIL') {
        console.log('Message is spam or contains virus, ignoring.');
        context.succeed();
    }

    var email = msgInfo.content,
        headers = "From: " + forwardFrom + "\r\n";
    headers += "Reply-To: " + msgInfo.mail.commonHeaders.from[0] + "\r\n";
    headers += "X-Original-To: " + msgInfo.mail.commonHeaders.to[0] + "\r\n";
    headers += "To: " + forwardTo + "\r\n";
    headers += "Subject: Fwd: " + msgInfo.mail.commonHeaders.subject + "\r\n";

    if (email) {
        var res;
        res = email.match(/Content-Type:.+\s*boundary.*/);
        if (res) {
            headers += res[0] + "\r\n";
        } else {
            res = email.match(/^Content-Type:(.*)/m);
            if (res) {
                headers += res[0] + "\r\n";
            }
        }

        res = email.match(/^Content-Transfer-Encoding:(.*)/m);
        if (res) {
            headers += res[0] + "\r\n";
        }

        res = email.match(/^MIME-Version:(.*)/m);
        if (res) {
            headers += res[0] + "\r\n";
        }

        var splitEmail = email.split("\r\n\r\n");
        splitEmail.shift();

        email = headers + "\r\n" + splitEmail.join("\r\n\r\n");
    } else {
        email = headers + "\r\n" + "Empty email";
    }

    new AWS.SES().sendRawEmail({
        RawMessage: { Data: email }
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) context.fail(err);
        else {
            console.log('Sent with MessageId: ' + data.MessageId);
            context.succeed();
        }
    });
}
```

*Note: You need to setup from_address, and to_address along with the IAM roles for this to work.*

For details steps refer the following medium article, which will also link to a Github repository with CloudFormation stack for automated provisioning.

[Forwarding Emails to your Inbox Using Amazon SES](https://medium.com/@ashan256/forwarding-emails-to-your-inbox-using-amazon-ses-2d261d60e417)

Alternatively you can use Amazon Workmail to receive the emails, but it will add a monthly subscription cost.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Am i understanding this correctly... When SES receives an email for `admin@domain.com`, a lambda function is invoked in order to forward that email to another email address such as `example@gmail.com`? If so, when `example@gmail.com` replys to the forwarded email, will the `From` address show the original intended recipient (`admin@domain.com`) or the forwarded-to email address (`example@gmail.com`)

Comment: Current code replaces the original senders email address so when you receive the email to gmail, it will be coming from the one you specify as from address. To keep the original senders address you might need to modify the code a bit so that you can reply directly back to the original sender.

Comment: `var splitEmail = email.split("\r\n\r\n")` splits the original email into an array with 2 string elements - the first string is the original headers, the second string is the original body. Then you discard the original headers, and prepend the original body with your new headers that you've just composed. But what's going on when you are composing those new headers? I understand that you are searching for a Content-Type header in a multi-part message first, and if that fails, then you search for a non-multi-part Content-Type, and you add this to your new headers. [continued...]

Comment: But why are you searching for Content-Transfer-Encoding? Won't that be included automatically anyway in the right position when you include the body of the original email? Also, why do you need to include the MIME-Version header? What happens if you just leave this out? It's a really nice, helpful answer, but it really bugs me when developers don't consider the _next_ developer who will come along to work on a piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Updated @Ashan's code for Node.js 18 and AWS SDK v3, the current recommended SES environment.

```
const {
    SESClient,
    SendRawEmailCommand
} = require("@aws-sdk/client-ses");
const forwardFrom = process.env.from_address;
const forwardTo = process.env.to_address;
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    const msgInfo = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].Sns.Message);

    // don't process spam messages
    if (msgInfo.receipt.spfVerdict.status === 'FAIL'
            || msgInfo.receipt.dkimVerdict.status === 'FAIL' 
            || msgInfo.receipt.spamVerdict.status === 'FAIL' 
            || msgInfo.receipt.virusVerdict.status === 'FAIL') {
        console.log('Message is spam or contains virus, ignoring.');
        context.succeed();
    }

    let email = msgInfo.content,
        headers = "From: " + forwardFrom + "\r\n";
    headers += "Reply-To: " + msgInfo.mail.commonHeaders.from[0] + "\r\n";
    headers += "X-Original-To: " + msgInfo.mail.commonHeaders.to[0] + "\r\n";
    headers += "To: " + forwardTo + "\r\n";
    headers += "Subject: Fwd: " + msgInfo.mail.commonHeaders.subject + ")\r\n";

    if (email) {
        let res;
        res = email.match(/Content-Type:.+\s*boundary.*/);
        if (res) {
            headers += res[0] + "\r\n";
        } else {
            res = email.match(/^Content-Type:(.*)/m);
            if (res) {
                headers += res[0] + "\r\n";
            }
        }

        res = email.match(/^Content-Transfer-Encoding:(.*)/m);
        if (res) {
            headers += res[0] + "\r\n";
        }

        res = email.match(/^MIME-Version:(.*)/m);
        if (res) {
            headers += res[0] + "\r\n";
        }

        let splitEmail = email.split("\r\n\r\n");
        splitEmail.shift();

        email = headers + "\r\n" + splitEmail.join("\r\n\r\n");
    } else {
        email = headers + "\r\n" + "Empty email";
    }

    const command = new SendRawEmailCommand({
        RawMessage: {
            Data: Buffer.from(email)
        }
    });
    const client = new SESClient();
    client.send(command)
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log('Sent with MessageId: ' + data.MessageId);
            context.succeed();
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            context.fail(err);
        });
};
```